# iOS OCMock call back method with parameter

Tags: ios, stub, ocmock

I want to use OCMock such that whenever `someMethod` is called with any argument, it calls `callBackMethod:` with argument "dict", which is an `NSDictionary`. I found `andCall:onObject:` but that doesn't seem to let you pass an argument. Is there a way to get this desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `andDo:` and execute whatever you want in the given block.

```
id yourMock;//...
NSDictionary *dictionary;//...
id anObject;//...

[[[yourMock stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    [anObject callBackMethod:dictionary];
}] someMethod];
```